# Female cat's urine smells like ammonia

Tags: cats, health, urination, drinking

My four-year-old female cat’s urine smells like ammonia. She’s been on antibiotics twice and it didn’t seem to help. She hardly drinks any water, so I’m wondering what food I could give her that has a higher water content than the canned food she’s eating. She does not eat dry food. She eats Sheba (we just started giving her Sheba). She’s been eating fancy feast since we brought her home at 11 weeks. Any ideas would be very helpful, as the vet gave her the antibiotics and I’m not happy with them because I don’t think they worked.

Comment: Any urine will smell of ammonia if it sits in kitty liter for "awhile" . .

Comment: You could try wet food that has lots of gravy, or go with something like 'Almo Nature HFC', some of their canned food types have a lot of juice. Then there are those canned 'Drink' things, typically that is just very small pieces of meat in broth or thin gravy. But if the cat does not eat any dry food, she'll need to drínk less compared to one that does only eat dry food. If you want to convince her to drink more, apart from a drinking fountain or turning on the faucet which some cats prefer to a bowl, you can try a tiny shot of lactose-free(!) milk or cream in the water.

Comment: Thank you so much